# Submit form always copying over first row of ACF sub field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a form which I'm trying to update the sub fields with the data using [ACF's `update_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) function.

I have a repeater field with the sub fields - "time", "posted by" and "comment".

At the moment it's adding the data to the sub fields on submit fine... the problem is that it's always adding it to the first row. How can I make sure it adds a new row?

```
<form action="#" id="form" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="forum-comment" name="forum-comment">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
// Check if form was submitted
$value = array();
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $comment = $_GET['forum-comment'];
  $time = date('d/m/Y g:i a', time());

  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  // Comments
  $id = get_the_id();
  $field_key = "field_5c90d272c7ca9";

  $value[] = array(
    "time"          => $time,
    "posted_by"     => $current_user->ID,
    "comment"           => $comment,
  );

  update_field( $field_key, $value, $id );
}
```

Comment: By making `$value` contain the old rows as well …

Comment: @04FS Ah of course, didn't think of that... even though I've done it a million times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone, pointed out by @04FS:

```
<?php
// Check if form was submitted
$value = array();
if( have_rows( 'comments' ) ):
  while( have_rows( 'comments' ) ): the_row();
    $time = get_sub_field( 'time' );
    $posted = get_sub_field( 'posted_by' );
    $comment = get_sub_field( 'comment' );

    $value[] = array(
      "time"        => $time,
      "posted_by"       => $posted,
      "comment"         => $comment,
    );

  endwhile;
endif;

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $comment = $_GET['forum-comment'];
  $time = date('d/m/Y g:i a', time());

  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  // Comments
  $id = get_the_id();
  $field_key = "field_5c90d272c7ca9";

  $value[] = array(
    "time"          => $time,
    "posted_by"     => $current_user->ID,
    "comment"           => $comment,
  );

  update_field( $field_key, $value, $id );
}
?>
```